# Require ruby file without .rb extension?

Tags: ruby, require, shebang

I have a ruby file that does not have a `.rb` extension, and is instead identified as ruby code with a shebang at the beginning of the file: `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`.  I want to `require` the code in this file in another ruby file, but it seems to be having a problem because `require` automatically appends the `.rb` extension to the files it looks for.  Is there any way to suppress this behavior and make require only look for the file as the name is given?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `load` instead:

```
load 'file-name'
```

Comment: Be aware of the differences in behavior between `load` and `require`. They aren't exactly replacements for each other.

Comment: One notable difference: `require` loads the file only once, `load` does it every time.  Docs: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-load

Comment: nice article describing the differences: https://medium.com/@connorstack/understanding-ruby-load-require-gems-bundler-and-rails-autoloading-from-the-bottom-up-3b422902ca0

Answer (score 3):

We have scripts the users are allowed to call, which are accessed using symlinks. The symlinks exist in our /usr/local/bin directory, which is automatically included in their path via a minor adjustment to /etc/profile.

Our real scripts exist in a separate directory using the normal Ruby name, ending with ".rb". We can access those using `require` if necessary.

```
/usr/local/bin/foo --> /usr/local/share/app_name/foo.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a symlink to the file and then require that.

```
ln -s bin/foo lib/stubs/foo.rb
require 'stubs/foo'
```